# How do I read a .csv file and save it into a 2d array?

Tags: c, file-io

I am quite new to C programming and I have been set the task of reading a .csv file containing a 2d integer array, I need to then print it so it shows up in the terminal. The array is a 4 row by 2 col integer array, but when I use this code I get a random list of numbers. I have attached the code I used and the .csv file array and how it should look like.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *in_data = fopen("in.csv", "r");
    
    int i;
    int j;
    int trIn[4][2];
    if(in_data == NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        char junk;

        if (j != 0) fgetc(in_data);

        fscanf(in_data, "%c%d%c", &junk, &trIn[i][j], &junk);
        printf("%d ", trIn[i][j]);
    }
    fgetc(in_data);
    printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

.csv file array:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

.csv file (raw):

```
"0","0"
"0","1"
"1","0"
"1","1"
```

Comment: can you give the raw .csv file data?

Comment: Mind that `fgetc` parses one **character** at a time, including spaces and newline characters.

Comment: thanks, last question: Are these numbers always a single character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace you current loop with this one:

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        char junk;

        if (j != 0) fgetc(in_data);

        fscanf(in_data, "%c%d%c", &junk, &trIn[i][j], &junk);
        printf("%d ", trIn[i][j]);
    }
    fgetc(in_data);
    printf("\n");
}
```

This works because `fscanf(in_data, "%d", &trIn[i][j])` reads an int (`%d`) from the file `in_data` into the memory location of `trIn[i][j]`. `fgetc` didn't work because it only reads a single character which was then printed as if it were an integer.

EDIT: Now, for each value in the .csv file, you read to a junk variable the `"` and `\n` characters.

Line by line:

`if (j != 0) fgetc(in_data);` reads the `,` from the csv file into a junk variable (which isn't the first character on a line).

`fscanf(in_data, "%c%d%c", &junk, &trIn[i][j], &junk);` reads:

- 1st: the opening `"` character into a junk variable
- 2nd: the number (int: `%d`) into to memory location of `trIn[i][j]`.
- 3rd: the closing `"` character into a junk variable

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223852/discussion-on-answer-by-polartocartesian-how-do-i-read-a-csv-file-and-save-it-i).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pattern which discards the unwanted characters, like so:

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/JudiciousUsefulServerapplication)</kbd>

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        //printf("%s", str); //print str to check if there are any weird chars
        fscanf(in_data, " \"%d\",", &trIn[i][j]);
        printf("%d ", trIn[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Chek if you have spaces in the lines after the values, that can throw `fscanf` off. Although a space before the specifier, like in the sample, should solve that.

Also, you can export `.csv` files without the quotation marks, if that's something you can control.

You can also try a more robust method using a combo of `fgets` and `sscanf`:

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/JudiciousUsefulServerapplication-1)</kbd>

```
char str[20];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

//...

while (i < 4 && fgets(str, sizeof str, in_data))
{
    //printf("%s", str); //print str to check if there are any weird chars
    if(sscanf(str, "\"%d\",\"%d\"", &trIn[i][j], &trIn[i][j+1]) == 2)
        printf("%d %d\n", trIn[i][j], trIn[i][j+1]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @xmxn I added another method, if ithis doesn't work, there is something seriously wrong with your file. Perhaps nor printable characters being parsed.

Comment: `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()` (or using a pair of pointers and `strtol()`) is always the way to go.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, for sure.